# Is a differentiable matrix function Lipschitz Continuous?

Tags: matrix-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Let $L_{\infty}(\mathbb{R^{n \times n}})$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices $A$ such that $\| A\|_{\infty} = \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |A_{ij}| < \infty$. Is it true that if $f:L_\infty (\mathbb{R^{n \times n}})\to L_\infty(\mathbb{R^{n \times n}})$ has an everywhere bounded bounded derivative  $\|f'(A)\|_{\infty} < \lambda$ then $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous in the sense that
$$\|f(A)-f(B)\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda\|A-B\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: What would be a derivative of a function $L_\infty (\mathbb R^{n\times n})\longrightarrow L^\infty (\mathbb R^{n\times n})$ ?

Comment: The notation $L_\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ looks like the space of $L_\infty$ functions taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$; I suggest something like $(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \ell_\infty)$ instead, or even shorter, $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be reduced to the scalar case. Let $\phi(t)=(1-t)A+tB$ be a parameterization of the line segment from $A$ to $B$. Also let $\psi$ be a unit-norm functional such that $$\psi(f(A)-f(B)) = \|f(A)-f(B)\|$$
Then $\psi\circ f \circ \phi$ is a real function of a real variable $t\in [0,1]$, and its derivative (by the chain rule) is bounded by 
$$\lambda \|A-B\|$$
where the second factor comes from $\phi'$. It follows that 
$$
\|\psi\circ f \circ \phi(1) - \psi\circ f \circ \phi(0)\| \le \lambda \|A-B\|
$$
which is the desired Lipschitz property.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I think there's a caveat that $\psi(X) = \|X\|_{\infty}$ is differentiable only when there's a unique row $i$ such that $\sum_{j} |X_{ij}|$ is maximized, and when $X_{ij} \neq 0$ for all (i,j), but this is true for a random positive matrix, which is the case I'm interested in.

Comment: Another issue is that the derivative of $\psi$ is a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 &...& 0 \\ ... & ... & .... & ... \\ 0& 0& ... &0 \\ 1& 1& ... &1 \\ 0& 0& ...& 0 \\ 0 &0& ...& 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so when using the chain rule we get

Comment: Forget matrices. It's a normed vector space, that is all you need to think about. The particulars are only distracting. Is the function f differentiable everywhere, or just almost everywhere? There was nothing about "almost everywhere" in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My comment got cut off in the middle. I meant to say that something works, but  one has to be careful with which norm pops out of the chain rule.  When using the chain rule we get

$$ (\psi \circ f \circ \phi)' = \psi' f'  (A-B)$$ and the bound I can get on $\|\psi' f' (A-B)\|_{\infty}$ from Holder's inequality is $\|\psi'\|_{\infty} \| f'(A-B)\|_1$ , which is a valid bound but depends on $n$

Comment: No, nothing depends on $n$. Forget $n$. Forget matrices. Everything works in a general normed space. This is my last comment here.